# Start second Rviz instance

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

can I start somehow two different Rviz instances which run on two different PC but connect to the same ROS master?

I have one ROS master running ROS Indigo. There I am running different tools to control a robot. Now I would like to connect with a second Linux PC to the first ROS master and start another Rviz instance to see the current state of the robot.
Is this possible and if yes, how do I have to specify the command on the second PC?

Best
matl

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270258/start-second-rviz-instance/) by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-09-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-05**:
Have you tried using `rosrun rviz rviz` on both and seeing what happens?

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-08**:
Thanks for the hint, I also had to do the export ROS_MASTER_URI=myipadress to conenct it to the master. But anyway I have trouble to see the robot in the second PC.
In Rviz I still cannot see the robot. Please see the uploaded picture which I did: https://ibb.co/fD1LjF

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-08**:
You should really update your answer with a proper *screenshot* vs a picture of your monitor taken with a camer/cellphone.

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-08**:
sorry, the PC is right now not connected to the internet so it was the only chance to get some kind of screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use `rosrun rviz rviz` on both computers. Should work.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible and you don't have to do anything special, just start it like normal. Are you having problems trying it?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-09-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matl](https://answers.ros.org/users/29014/matl/) on 2017-09-08**:
Like mentioned above, I found one small operator misstake ;-)
but I still do not see the whole robot: https://ibb.co/fD1LjF

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-09-08**:
That sounds like a new unrelated problem that we don't have enough information to help with yet. I'd open up a new question that describes the problem in more detail.

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-09-08**:
As a tip for the future, it's best to do actual screenshots rather than a photo of a screen, and post the actual screenshot rather than a link to it, I think it increases your chances of getting people to help.